# Different colors and Metamerism

Tags: optics, visible-light, wavelength

Given the following graphs:

[image]

They describe the response for two different colors .
In addition that both colors are [*metamerism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamerism_%28color%29).

My question is why? how can I prove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple physical model of the eye (or indeed a typical camera) is that it records just three values for each pixel. In your eye, this is because you have three different types of [cone cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_cell), called S, M, and L, peaking in blue, green, and red wavelengths. In a camera, the light is passed through blue, green, and red filters before having its intensity recorded.

The result is projecting the full spectral information onto a three-dimensional subspace of color. Mathematically, this is done by convolving the original spectrum with the response function of the cones/filters. Your eyes' response functions are given [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cone-fundamentals-with-srgb-spectrum.png):

[image: cone response functions]

Imagine writing these as functions of wavelength, e.g. $S(\lambda)$ for the S cone. Then if your source has a spectrum $F(\lambda)$, the S cone will record a response of
$$ R_S = \int\limits_\text{visible light} F(\lambda) S(\lambda)\, \mathrm{d}\lambda. $$
Similarly you can calculate $R_M$ and $R_L$. Then any spectra $F_1,F_2$ for which $R_{1S} = R_{2S}$, $R_{1M} = R_{2M}$, and $R_{1L} = R_{2L}$, the colors appear the same and they are said to be metameric.

We conclude that the map $F \mapsto (R_S,R_M,R_L)$ that calculates the responses is not injective -- different $F$'s can map to the same triplet. It is also not surjective -- there are triplets of responses that cannot be generated from any $F$. See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48224/is-it-possible-that-there-is-a-color-our-human-eye-cant-see) for more on so-called imaginary colors.